# Issue regarding .Find method in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In this line of code here

```
w6 = Range(NewNewNewDataColumn & MOPNumber":" & NewNewNewDataColumn).Find(What:=w5, after:=Range(NewNewNewDataColumn & 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

I am looking for w5 in a column which goes

```
Row 1 = 25 
Row 2 = 24 
Row 3 = 23 
.
.
. 
Row 26 = 0 
Row 27 = 1 
Row 28 = 2 
.
.
.
Row 49 = 23
Row 50 = 48 
Row 51 = 25
```

This method is used as these number are referance points for Cells that contain the useful information.

where w5 is the number 0 to 25. Works fine expect for one slightly major issue, which is instead of finding the number "1" its fine the first mention of 1 so in this case "21" So will give back the row number for the number 21 not the number 1. Is there a way to change the code to search for the entire mention of w5. Does that make sense?

Thank for any help your able to provide
Mark

Comment: There are many more arguments for the find method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  `LookAt` can be set to look at the whole cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner that solved it, thanks a bunch, submit it as an answer and ill accept it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
w6 = Range(NewNewNewDataColumn & ":" & NewNewNewDataColumn).Find(What:=w5, after:=Range(NewNewNewDataColumn & 1), LookAt:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
```

Above is the line of code thatg I used and solved it, the `LookAt:=xlWhole` i belive was the critical statement within the line enabling the code to work as intended.